# Can not log on to windows to show google chrome password

Tags: windows-10, passwords

maybe this is a silly question but I am in a problem. Please help me!!

I am able to login to my `windows 10` local system through my password as an administrator. My system is an `Education` version. I know that, there are couple of ways to show my saved password in `google chrome`. google chrome shows credentials related window with `show` option.

[image] [image]

I clicked on show, then it pops up a window that ask for `windows administrative password`. I provide the same password as I logged into my system. It shows `windows is unable you to log on`.
I saw my password same way before.

What is going wrong on?

Comment: does just pressing 'OK' help?

Comment: No its not working ... @Luciferangel